# Installing OpenDKIM on Amazon Linux 2023

Tags: amazon-linux-2023, opendkim

Trying to install and run oepndkim against sendmail on AmazonLinux 2023

Have been able to build and run:

make install

This does not seem to install the opendkim.service.
Does not install the opendkim user either

The opendkim/README does not say how to do this